# Can connect to postgres container through shell but not through phoenix app

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a postgres container launched with this configuration:

```
# Version of docker-compose
version: '3'

# Containers we are going to run
services:
  db:
    # We use the predefined Postgres image
    image: postgres:12
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres_db
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    restart: on-failure
```

And I can connect through my local shell outside the container like this as expected because ports 5432 are exposed:

```
psql -h localhost postgres_db postgres
```

But it's strange phoenix cannot connect, phoenix config is the following one:

```
# Configure your database
config :phoenix_chat, PhoenixChat.Repo
  username: "postgres",
  password: "postgres",
  database: "postgres_db",
  hostname: "localhost",
  pool_size: 10,
  # Help diagnose connection errors:
  show_sensitive_data_on_connection_error: true
```

It crashes with this:

```
Generated phoenix_chat app
[error] GenServer #PID<0.382.0> terminating
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    :erlang.binary_to_integer("12beta1")
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1327: Enum."-map/2-lists^map/1-0-"/2
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex/utils.ex:68: Postgrex.Utils.parse_version/1
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex/protocol.ex:796: Postgrex.Protocol.bootstrap_send/6
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex/protocol.ex:577: Postgrex.Protocol.handshake/2
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:66: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
    (connection) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: nil
State: Postgrex.Protocol
[error] GenServer #PID<0.414.0> terminating
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    :erlang.binary_to_integer("12beta1")
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1327: Enum."-map/2-lists^map/1-0-"/2
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex/utils.ex:68: Postgrex.Utils.parse_version/1
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex/protocol.ex:796: Postgrex.Protocol.bootstrap_send/6
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex/protocol.ex:577: Postgrex.Protocol.handshake/2
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:66: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
    (connection) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: nil
State: Postgrex.Protocol
[error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.380.0>) failed to connect: ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) awaited on another connection that failed to bootstrap types
[error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.384.0>) failed to connect: ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) awaited on another connection that failed to bootstrap types
[error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.383.0>) failed to connect: ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) awaited on another connection that failed to bootstrap types
[error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.388.0>) failed to connect: ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) awaited on another connection that failed to bootstrap types
[error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.385.0>) failed to connect: ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) awaited on another connection that failed to bootstrap types
[error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.389.0>) failed to connect: ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) awaited on another connection that failed to bootstrap types
[error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.381.0>) failed to connect: ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) awaited on another connection that failed to bootstrap types
[error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.387.0>) failed to connect: ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) awaited on another connection that failed to bootstrap types
[error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.386.0>) failed to connect: ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) awaited on another connection that failed to bootstrap types
[error] GenServer #PID<0.416.0> terminating
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    :erlang.binary_to_integer("12beta1")
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1327: Enum."-map/2-lists^map/1-0-"/2
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex/utils.ex:68: Postgrex.Utils.parse_version/1
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex/protocol.ex:796: Postgrex.Protocol.bootstrap_send/6
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex/protocol.ex:577: Postgrex.Protocol.handshake/2
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:66: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
    (connection) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: nil
State: Postgrex.Protocol
[error] GenServer #PID<0.417.0> terminating
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    :erlang.binary_to_integer("12beta1")
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1327: Enum."-map/2-lists^map/1-0-"/2
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex/utils.ex:68: Postgrex.Utils.parse_version/1
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex/protocol.ex:796: Postgrex.Protocol.bootstrap_send/6
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex/protocol.ex:577: Postgrex.Protocol.handshake/2
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:66: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
    (connection) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: nil
State: Postgrex.Protocol
[info] Running PhoenixChatWeb.Endpoint with cowboy 2.6.3 at 0.0.0.0:4000 (http)
[info] Access PhoenixChatWeb.Endpoint at http://localhost:4000
[error] GenServer #PID<0.524.0> terminating
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    :erlang.binary_to_integer("12beta1")
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1327: Enum."-map/2-lists^map/1-0-"/2
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex/utils.ex:68: Postgrex.Utils.parse_version/1
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex/protocol.ex:796: Postgrex.Protocol.bootstrap_send/6
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex/protocol.ex:577: Postgrex.Protocol.handshake/2
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:66: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
    (connection) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: nil
State: Postgrex.Protocol
[error] GenServer #PID<0.530.0> terminating
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    :erlang.binary_to_integer("12beta1")
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1327: Enum."-map/2-lists^map/1-0-"/2
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex/utils.ex:68: Postgrex.Utils.parse_version/1
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex/protocol.ex:796: Postgrex.Protocol.bootstrap_send/6
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex/protocol.ex:577: Postgrex.Protocol.handshake/2
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:66: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
    (connection) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: nil
State: Postgrex.Protocol
[error] GenServer #PID<0.527.0> terminating
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    :erlang.binary_to_integer("12beta1")
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1327: Enum."-map/2-lists^map/1-0-"/2
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex/utils.ex:68: Postgrex.Utils.parse_version/1
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex/protocol.ex:796: Postgrex.Protocol.bootstrap_send/6
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex/protocol.ex:577: Postgrex.Protocol.handshake/2
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:66: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
    (connection) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: nil
```

I also tried to connect through `iex` shell using `postgrex`

```
{:ok, pid} = Postgrex.start_link(hostname: "localhost", username: "postgres", password: "postgres", database: "postgres_db")
```

But it also gives the same error.

postgres container outputs these errors:

```
db_1  | 2019-06-11 12:38:05.127 UTC [542] LOG:  PID 528 in cancel request did not match any process
db_1  | 2019-06-11 12:38:05.205 UTC [557] LOG:  PID 549 in cancel request did not match any process
db_1  | 2019-06-11 12:38:05.244 UTC [575] LOG:  PID 570 in cancel request did not match any process
```

Comment: This is an issue with the postgrex driver. I have created an issue for it [here](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/postgrex/issues/464).

Comment: As already mentioned by @JustinWood, the problem is the version number of Postgres which cannot be parsed by the postgrex driver. Good news is that there is already a [commit referenced](https://github.com/am-kantox/postgrex/commit/9d499f3afa02df84ec32f25c5a3bf3d741b114c2) that should fix the issue.

Comment: ok thanks, I thought it was something about my config and was driving me nuts but looks like I can downgrade postgrex for now and it will work

Comment: It was just merged into `master` FWIW. Use `{:postgrex, github: "elixir-ecto/postgrex"}` until it’d be released as a version update,

Answer (score -1):

```
iex(1)> :erlang.binary_to_integer("12beta1")
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    :erlang.binary_to_integer("12beta1")

iex(1)> :erlang.binary_to_integer("12")     
12

iex(2)> :erlang.binary_to_integer("12a")
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    :erlang.binary_to_integer("12a")

iex(2)>
```

Did you name something `"12beta1"`?  If it helps, here's my config file:

```
config :auction, ecto_repos: [Auction.Repo]

config :auction, Auction.Repo,
  database: "auction",
  username: "7stud",
  password: "",
  hostname: "localhost",
  port: "5432"
```

My app is an umbrella app, where the phoenix app, `auction_web`, does not use a database, rather the `auction` app and its user interface employ the database, and that db configuration is in `auction_umbrella/apps/auction/config/config.exs`.  The `auction_web` app is the other app in the `auction_umbrella/apps` dir.

Comment: `12beta1` is the version of postgres they are using.

Comment: @JustinWood, Well then, the error tells me that you cannot use a beta version of postgres with phoenix.

Comment: Agreed. A bit pedantic, but this is not a phoenix issue. It is a postgrex issue. It is possible other postgres drivers work correctly here.